# ListView displaying audio and video from mediastore

Tags: android, cursor, media, mediastore

I'm trying to create a list that shows both audio and video from the mediastore. However, I'm not sure how to create such a query - is it even possible to get information for both audio and video at the same time?

So to query for video and audio I do this:

```
String[] projV = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN };

Cursor videoCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projV, null,
                null, null);

String[] projA = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED };
Cursor audioCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projA, null,
                null, null);
```

I looked into using `CursorJoiner` or `MergeCursor`, but I'm not sure how to use these or even certain its the right solution.

So my question is; Is there a way to construct a query for the mediaStore that returns a cursor with information for both audio and video or do I need to something more complex such as using `CursorJoiner` or `MergeCursor`.

As I mentioned at the start, my goal is to have a list displaying all the audio and video in the mediastore - is this the right approach or am I looking at it from a wrong angle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible from API-11 by using MediaStore.Files with an appropriate selection clause.

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle)
{
    final String PROJECTION[] = {FileColumns._ID, FileColumns.DATA, FileColumns.DATE_ADDED};
    final String ORDER = FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
    final String SELECTION =  "(" + FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "=" + FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO +") OR (" + FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "=" + FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE + ")";
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Files.getContentUri("external"), PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, ORDER);
}
```

Prior to that you can use a MergeCursor if you don't care about sort order. Look at MatrixCursor if you need to manage sort order. Alternatively wrap your cursors in a CursorWrapper that implements order logic.